# Frequence in a df without repetition R

Tags: dataframe, repeat, frequency

hello I have the df "dress"

```
      type   size  color
1  t-shirt  small   blue
2  t-shirt medium   blue
3    jeans  large yellow
4    skirt  small   pink
5    skirt medium yellow
6   blouse  large   blue
7    jeans  small   blue
8  t-shirt medium   blue
9    skirt  large yellow
10  blouse  large   pink
```

I'm calculating how many times the color is "blue" with

```
sum(dress$color == "blue")
```

The result is 5 and among these there are 3 t-shirt. I'd like to know only how many "type" are blue, so if type "t-shirt" is repeated I'd like it to be counted just one time. The question is: "in how many types the color "blue" is repeated?"  So, with this conditions the result should be 2. How I can do it?

Also, I'd like to know how many times a type is repeated, for example an information like "t-shirt blue is repeated 3 times".

df is :

```
dput(dress)
structure(list(type = c("t-shirt", "t-shirt", "jeans", "skirt", 
"skirt", "blouse", "jeans", "t-shirt", "skirt", "blouse"), size = c("small", 
"medium", "large", "small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium", 
"large", "large"), color = c("blue", "blue", "yellow", "pink", 
"yellow", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", "pink"), freqBlue = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, `dplyr` is what you are looking for.

```
dt %>%
  group_by(type, color) %>%
  summarise(
    freq =n()
  )
```

Where `dt` is your `data.frame`, the script yields the following output,

```
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   type [4]
  type    color   freq
  <chr>   <chr>  <int>
1 blouse  blue       1
2 blouse  pink       1
3 jeans   blue       1
4 jeans   yellow     1
5 skirt   pink       1
6 skirt   yellow     2
7 t-shirt blue       3
```

Here `n()` counts the number of occurrences group-wise, and you can keep adding groups!

Comment: this answer is useful for the second question, but I need frequence without repetiton. The question is: in how many types the color "blue" is repeated?

Comment: Ooooh! I think I understand it now. If your data is as posted, then you can just remove `type` in the code; then it will count the occurrences of each `color` which by definition is the occurrences of the `color` across all `types`, `sizes` etc.